# Generic implementation depending on traits

Tags: generics, rust, traits

When defining a generic `struct`, is there a way in **Rust** to use different implementation of a method according to which trait is implemented by the given generic type `T`?

For example:

```
struct S<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl<T> S<T> {
    fn print_me(&self) {
        println!("I cannot be printed");
    }
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Display> S<T> {
    fn print_me(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S { value: 2 };
    s.print_me();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. That [will be possible](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ee68f072be71d2159f58b408679b5418) once specialization lands, but it might [take a while](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844). Also, you probably meant `s.print_me()` instead of than `s.do_it()`.

Comment: @user4815162342 you are right, edited

Comment: If you are okay with making `print_me` a macro, this is possible today on stable rust: https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/blob/master/autoref-specialization/README.md

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an unstable feature known as [`specialization`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) which permits multiple `impl`
blocks to apply to the same type as long as one of the blocks is *more specific* than the other:

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

struct Printer<T>(T);

trait Print {
    fn print(&self);
}

// specialized implementation
impl<T: fmt::Display> Print for Printer<T> {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.0);
    }
}

// default implementation
impl<T> Print for Printer<T> {
    default fn print(&self) {
        println!("I cannot be printed");
    }
}


struct NotDisplay;

fn main() {
    let not_printable = Printer(NotDisplay);
    let printable = Printer("Hello World");

    not_printable.print();
    printable.print();
}

// => I cannot be printed
// => Hello World
```

On stable Rust, we'll need some other mechanism to accomplish specialization. Rust has another language feature capable of doing this: [method resolution autoref](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/blob/master/autoref-specialization/README.md). The compiler's rule is that if a method can be dispatched without autoref then it will be. Only if a method cannot be dispatched without autoref, the compiler will insert an autoref and attempt to resolve it again. So in this example:

```rust
impl Print for Value {
    fn print(self) {
        println!("Called on Value");
    }
}

impl Print for &Value {
    fn print(self) {
        println!("Called on &Value");
    }
}
```

The implementation for `Value` will be prioritized over `&Value`. Knowing this rule, we can mimic specialization in stable Rust:

```rust
struct Printer<T>(T);

trait Print {
    fn print(&self);
}

// specialized implementation
impl<T: fmt::Display> Print for Printer<T> {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.0);
    }
}

trait DefaultPrint {
    fn print(&self);
}

// default implementation
//
// Note that the Self type of this impl is &Printer<T> and so the 
// method argument is actually &&T! 
// That makes this impl lower priority during method
// resolution than the implementation for `Print` above.
impl<T> DefaultPrint for &Printer<T> {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("I cannot be printed");
    }
}

struct NotDisplay;

fn main() {
    let not_printable = Printer(NotDisplay);
    let printable = Printer("Hello World");
    
    (&not_printable).print();
    (&printable).print();
}

// => I cannot be printed
// => Hello World
```

The compiler will try to use the `Print` implementation first. If it can't (because the type is not `Display`), it will then use the more general implementation of `DefaultPrint`.

The way that this technique applies method resolution cannot be described by a trait bound, so it will not work for regular methods, as we would have to choose between one of the traits (`DefaultPrint` or `Print`):

```rust
fn print<T: ???>(value: T) {
    (&value).print()
}
```

However, this trick can be very useful to macros, which do not need to spell out trait bounds:

```rust
macro_rules! print {
    ($e:expr) => {
        (&$e).print()
    };
}


print!(not_printable); // => I cannot be printed
print!(printable); // => Hello World
```

Comment: To add a couple of things to this: This doesn't actually need a macro to work, that's just sugar.  And it won't work on generics to functions: if defining 

    fn run<T>(something : T) { 
        let checker = S { value: something };
        print_me!(checker);
    }

Then run("hello"); will still result in "I cannot be printed."

Comment: @DanielV Good points, I'll update the answer.