# Implement a struct's function for specific type in Rust

Tags: rust

In code below, I am trying to implement a generic struct. What I want to achieve is, for T whose type is String, print `self.x` value, and for all other types, print both `self.x` and `self.y`.

This question is not relevant to `trait`, I only tried to `impl` functions for a struct.

```
use core::fmt::Display;
use core::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T
}

impl Point<String> {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.x);
    }
}

impl<T: Display + Debug> Point<T> {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.x);
        println!("{:?}", self.y);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Point{x: String::from("123"), y: String::from("456")};
    let y = Point{x: 123, y: 456};
    //let z = Point{x: vec![1,2,3], y: vec![4,5,6]};
    
    x.print();
    y.print();
    //z.print();
}
```

However, I got the compile error below:

```
error[E0592]: duplicate definitions with name `print`
```

What is the correct way to achieve it?

Moreover, I also tried to use vectors as x and y(the `z` in main), which is not allow, I want to know the reason.

Comment: you want specialization ? search for it on SO there should be some question about that already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic implementation depending on traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955738/generic-implementation-depending-on-traits)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust doesn't support specialization yet, but there is a [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) for the same. But your requirement can be satisfied by checking [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html).

```rust
fn is_string<T: Any>() -> bool {
    TypeId::of::<String>() == TypeId::of::<T>()
}

impl<T: Debug + Any> Point<T> {
    fn print(&self) {
        if is_string::<T>() {
            println!("{:?}", self.x);
        } else {
            println!("{:?}", self.x);
            println!("{:?}", self.y);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f730592343ab3f280b4e131b3c9a8f3)

This code will also work for vectors. In your code you added a trait bound for [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) which is not implemented by [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

Comment: Just note that you have to be careful with this because `TypeId::of` is very literal, so `is_string()` will return true only for actual `String`, not for e.g. `&'static str`. Also, it won't work for any `T` that contains a non-static lifetime (there was a suggestion to change this, but it got [rejected](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41875)).