# Conditional Drop trait implementation for generic types

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement additional behaviour for a generic type if its type parameters meet particular trait bounds:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    data: T
}

impl<T> Drop for Foo<T> where T: Debug {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?} has been deallocated", self.data);
    }
}
```

The idea being that Foo would implement Drop if T implements Debug, while still allowing Foo to be used for types T without Debug (which simply won't implement Drop). However, this results in a compiler error:

```
`Drop` impl requires `T: Debug` but the struct it is implemented for does not
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour (without splitting Foo into two separate types)?

This discussion suggests that this is not possible (or at least wasn't at the time):

- [`Drop` impl requires `T: Debug` but the struct it is implemented for does not](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/drop-impl-requires-t-debug-but-the-struct-it-is-implemented-for-does-not/57763)

Apparently this is only an issue for the `Drop` trait, for other traits it works just fine:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    data: T
}

trait MyDrop {
    fn drop(&mut self);
}

impl<T> MyDrop for Foo<T> where T: Debug {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?} has been deallocated", self.data);
    }
}
```

So I guess my real question is: Why is conditional destructor implementation different from conditional implementation of other traits?

Comment: This discussion: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/drop-impl-requires-t-debug-but-the-struct-it-is-implemented-for-does-not/57763 suggests that this is not possible (or at least wasn't at the time).

Comment: This is still true.

Comment: Any reason why this is prohibited, and is this something that will be addressed in the future? Conditional implementation of Foo methods seems to work fine (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and thinking about it some more, I believe the issue is that allowing conditional implementation for Drop would cause a conflict with the compiler-generated default implementation of Drop. That's similar to the way you cannot currently specialize an implementation, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955738/generic-implementation-depending-on-traits).

However, once [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) becomes stable it might be possible to allow conditional implementation of Drop as well. Does that sound correct?